# Unable to force msbuild to disable TreatWarningAsError

Tags: msbuild

I'm building a some project chain. For normal coding I set in each project TreatWarningAsError to true.

But now I want to prepare code analysis and I want to disable this setting to be able to display all warnings form all projects.

```
msbuild smth.proj /t:SomeTarget
/p:RunCodeAnalysis=true 
/p:TreatWarningAsError=false 
/p:CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors=false
```

But I still get error:

```
error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
```

And compilation stops. 
But when I just make:

```
msbuild smth.proj /t:SomeTarget
```

Then it is ok.

What other setting should I check?
What other settings could result in rising C2220 error? 
How properties override works? Command line arguemnts overrides *.proj settings which overrides *.vcxproj settings?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. And as you said using those flags makes no different on the output